# functions-framework-nodejs PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless

Hy there!
How are you?

I'm developing a [Google Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions) and it is great!
But since last week I'm getting an issue testing locally with [functions-framework-nodejs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs)

```
Unhandled rejection
Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/home/user/project/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/user/project/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:176:52)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/user/project/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:342:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/user/project/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:305:181)
    at Http2CallStream.outputStatus (/home/user/project/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:117:74)
    at Http2CallStream.maybeOutputStatus (/home/user/project/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:156:22)
    at Http2CallStream.endCall (/home/user/project/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:142:18)
    at Http2CallStream.handleTrailers (/home/user/project/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:274:14)
    at ClientHttp2Stream.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at ClientHttp2Stream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:466:23)
Error: Process exited with code 16
    at process.on.code (/home/user/project/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:271:38)
    at process.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at process.exit (internal/process/per_thread.js:168:15)
    at Object.logAndSendError (/home/user/project/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/logger.js:37:9)
    at process.on.err (/home/user/project/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:268:22)
    at process.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at emitPromiseRejectionWarnings (internal/process/promises.js:140:18)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:69:34)
error Command failed with exit code 16.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

It occurs at the end of the execution of the function.

Any clue of what it is?

Thanks!

Update:

After José Soni ask me about the code, a tried to isolate some parts of the code and it seems to be LogginWinston it's causing the error, when i comment the "loggingWinston" on the creation of the logger, it works just fine. I've check the log API permission and it seems fine. the code is below!

```js
/** libraries */
const winston = require('winston')
const { LoggingWinston } = require('@google-cloud/logging-winston')

const loggingWinston = new LoggingWinston()

// Create a Winston logger that streams to Stackdriver Logging
// Logs will be written to: "projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/logs/winston_log"
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      level: 'debug',
      format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.colorize(),
        winston.format.simple()
      )
    }),
    // Add Stackdriver Logging
    loggingWinston
  ]
})

exports.execute = async (_request, response) => {
  logger.info('START')
  response.status(200).end()
}
```

Comment: could you share the code of the cloud function, and the user executing it, this is to know why the permission dennied is being triggered.

Comment: Hi @JoséSoní I've update the post with the code, by the user you mean the local user or the GCP user? The local user is my default linux user, and in the GCP i'm the owner of the project. Thanks!

Comment: I refer to the user in GCP account, which service account is associated to the cloud function? is it the defailt one?

Comment: Yes it's the default user!

Comment: is the error happenning when executing the deployed cloud function or when testing locally?

Comment: The error occurs only locally

Comment: @JoséSoní Hi there! I've update the main post with the answer. Thanks for the support!

Comment: If you post the answer as an answer to your question I'll be happy to upvote

Answer (score 1):

I think i found out the problem, it's not really a problem, but it seems to be in the @google-cloud/logging-winston.

It was missing a permission for the Logging API on the service account.
I think just the message it wasn't much clear.

But the code is right here:

https://github.com/denisdnc/cloud-functions-example

Set a service account credentials path:

```sh
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/credential.json"
```

And start the app:

```sh
npx @google-cloud/functions-framework --target=execute
```

Do the request on http://localhost:8080/

Then should log the problem above.

Thank you guys for the support!